# How to break out of or exit a void method in Scala?

Tags: scala

This is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. In a Scala method with no return value, how can I exit the method prematurely?

For example,

```
def printPositiveNumbersSum (n1: Int, n2: Int) = {
    if (n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
        // How do I break out of this method here?
    println(n1 + n2)
}
```

Attempting to use `return` like in Java raises an error that `printPositiveNumbersSum` doesn't have a return type.

I know that I could just make this an if-else statement, but if there are multiple conditions under which I'd like to exit the method and return to its caller, this becomes unwieldy quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic questions have a habit of being more interesting than they look. There are a couple of ways to approach this which are possibly worth considering as alternatives. The foundation though, is that everything returns a value of a certain type, and the compiler tries to figure out what that type is. In your case `printPostiveNumbersSum` returns something of a certain type.

- Let your method return a unit. The type `Unit` means a function, or piece of executable code. This answer has already been mentioned.
- Consider returning an Option[Int] for the sum. If the validation succeeds, you return `Some(sum)` and if it fails you return `None`. The caller can then decide what to do in the case of failure, perhaps using a `match { case Some(sum)...` construct.

  ```
  def positiveNumbersSum (n1: Int, n2: Int): Option[Int] = {
    if (n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
      None
    else Some(n1 + n2)
  }
  ```
- But in more complex cases, when you may have more rules to consider, it can be handy to return the *reason* for the failure rather than just returning a `None`. In this case, I find `Either` handy. You get to specify two return types. Again, the caller can differentiate with a `match { case Left(reason)... case Right(sum)...` construct.

  ```
  def positiveNumbersSum (n1: Int, n2: Int): Either[String,Int] = {
    if (n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
      Left("One of the numbers is negative")
    else Right(n1 + n2)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify Unit return type from your method

```
   def printPositiveNumbersSum(n1: Int, n2: Int): Unit = {
     if (n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
       return
     println(n1 + n2)
   }
```

and it then keeps scala compiler happy.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip your logic and avoid having to use the return keyword.

```
def printPositiveNumbersSum (n1: Int, n2: Int) = {
  if (n1 >= 0 && n2 >= 0)
    println(n1 + n2)
}
```

You should not have multiple exit points to a method, if you find yourself running into this problem, you should re-evaluate your solution.

Also the return keyword in scala is a little non intuitive. If you had a list of `Int` pairs, and you want to iterate the list, printing all the poisitive pairs, you might write a function like so:

```
def printMany(l: List[(Int, Int)]): Unit =
    l.foreach { case (n1, n2) =>
      if (n1 < 0 || n2 < 0) return
      println(n1 + n2)
    }
```

Now what exactly is the return keyword going to do in this scenario? Well given a list `val l = List((1,1), (2,2), (-1, 2), (5,4))`, it will print 2, 4, and then it will stop. The return keyword returns from the entire method, not the nested lambda.

For this reason, it is a good idea to avoid using return in scala for the most part.

Comment: "You should not have multiple exit points to a method" http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from